# Undefined offset 2

Tags: php, excel

Im trying to import the `.csv` file in php but im getting an error `undefined offset:2` and the data inserted in my database is only 0. Can someone help me or give me clues on how to fix this?

here's the error.
[image]

**UPDATE** when i tried `var_dump` the result is..
[image]

here is my code

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST["Import"])){


        echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];


         if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
         {

            $file = fopen($filename, "r");
             while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
             {

              //It wiil insert a row to our subject table from our csv file`
                  $sql = "INSERT into accounts (`acct_code`, `acct_name`) 
                    values('$emapData[1]','$emapData[2]')";
             //we are using mysql_query function. it returns a resource on true else False on error
              $result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
                if(! $result )
                {
                    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                            alert(\"Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File.\");
                            window.location = \"index.php\"
                        </script>";

                }

             }
             fclose($file);
             //throws a message if data successfully imported to mysql database from excel file
             echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\");
                        window.location = \"index.php\"
                    </script>";



             //close of connection
            mysql_close($conn); 



         }
    }    
?>
```

Comment: Is the seperator in the CSV a `,` or a `;` ? If it's seperated by semicolons you need to change it in `fgetcsv()` and it will split the columns correctly.

Comment: @Bert i think it's `,` The file type of excel is `Microsoft Excel Comma Seperated Values`

Comment: Can you double check it by opening the file in notepad?

Comment: @Bert it's `,` sir.

Comment: What does it show when you do a `var_dump($emapData);` within the `while()` loop?

Comment: i edit my question i post the result there.

Comment: I think the result is pretty clear... you should use indexes [0] and [1] instead of [1] and [2].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value $emapData[2] is not set. It means your csv data has no data for third column for that row.
please check your csv file.if the first and second column is what you need to insert in DB from csv then your query values should be $emapData[0],$emapData[1]

```
$sql = "INSERT into accounts (acct_code, acct_name) 
                values($emapData[0],'$emapData[1]')";
```

Comment: but the excel file in the second column have data.. :3 all the data inserted in first column is all 0 and the second column is blank :3

Comment: remove the quotes in $emapData[0]

Comment: with quotes $emapData[0] is taken as string.. When storing to db the string will store as 0 in int column

Comment: Still no change. But when i inserted the data there is error showing `C:\xampp\tmp\php2655.tmp` what is this?